# Selenium- Run a method once and use the return value for all @Test methods in the class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My requirement goes like this.

1. Log in to the application and open the System property menu to return a value of the property.
2. Open Another menu in the application and based on the value returned in the above step, perform the test scenario.

The problem is, for each @Test methods in the same class I need to perform both step 1 and 2 which is a time taking and unnecessary. The property retrieved from 'step 1' will be the same throughout the execution of the tests in the class.

Is there anyway I can execute 'step 1' **just once** at the start of the test and use the property value returned for all the @Test methods in the class following it?

P.S- I checked on the ***dependsOnMethods*** annotation and not sure whether it is a solution I am looking for.

Comment: Why not create a `public ` field at class level and assign  value from step1 and use it all other places

Comment: @Siva, Is there any annotations I should use for the method which returns the value in step 1. Can you illustrate with a small syntax?

Comment: i never worked on Annotations, i had always worked with customized frameworks only

Comment: `@BeforeTest`, `@BeforeClass` from testng can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JUnit, it sounds like `@BeforeClass` is what you are looking for. Method with this annotation runs only once per class and you can store any value returned in a global variable. Or, you might consider `@Before` annotation (runs before each test) if that suits you better.

Other testing frameworks use similar idea.

Comment: '@BeforeClass' might be the one I am looking for. Should I include the method name of the @BeforeClass in the 'testng.xml' file

Comment: Actually no need for '@BeforeClass' annotation for my requirement. Like @Siva told, creating a public field and assigning the value from step 1 solves my requirement. The step 1 method must be denoted by '@Test' annotation and it should be added in the testng.xml and test specification.

Comment: I agree w/ @Siva, assigning step 1 result to a global variable available to all methods is correct. However, make it `private` rather than `public` if you do not intend to use it in any other class (as private as possible is a common convention). Also, the `@Before...` annotations are there for a reason. If you perform step1 in `@Test` there is no guarantee of order the tests are run. `@BeforeClass` is the way since it will always execute first, no matter where it is placed in the class. See this tutorial for details [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_execution_procedure.htm).